# Fetch contents of a row from HTML table using '<tr onclick=alertContents()>'

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

i fetched and displayed data as a table in html from mysql db using jsp and java now what i want is when a user clicks on the particular row then the data in that row should populate in 3 different  tags
example if my table has this data

Name      Place    Mobile number

```
a         abc         123
b         def         234
c         ghi         345
```

(The above table is fetched from mysql db)

if the user clicks on the 3rd Row then the data such as name place and mobile number should be displayed in 3 different  tags as shown below

```
Name: c
Place: ghi
Mobile: 345
```

thanks in advance

Before i used to have a button on the right side of each row with the "Name"(if it is a row of c then the button has c) on it so i dressed the button by a pic using CSS.

here goes the code i used

```
  <form action="Options2" method="post">
 <table id="sorter" class="sortable" id="example" class="pretty">
 <tr>
<th>Book Id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Status</th>            
<th>Owner</th>
<th>Borrow Date</th>
<th>Return Date</th>
<th>Requested By</th>
<th>Actions</th>            
</tr>
<%
ArrayList  rs=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("news");
ListIterator itr=rs.listIterator();
int i=1;

while( itr.hasNext()){ 
%> 
<tr> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<% int Id = itr.nextIndex(); %>
<td><%=itr.next()%></td>    
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<% int Id2 = itr.nextIndex(); %>
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td><%=itr.next()%></td>
<% 
String Bname=rs.get(Id).toString();
System.out.println(Bname); 
String Stat=rs.get(Id2).toString();
System.out.println(Stat); 
if(!Stat.equals("Not Availible"))
{
%>
<td>
<input class="buttonir" type="Submit" name="X" value="<%=Bname %>"></td>
</tr>
<% 
}
}
%>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: maybe you could spread your idea on implementation, so that we can comment rather than expect solution from outside

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention.. This is really about HTML/JS, and you do this the same way in Java/JSP as ASP or PHP or..  In other words, this has absolutely *nothing* to do with Java/JSP beyond that those technologies are (supposedly) producing the HTML.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just edited my code to show how i used it before.

Comment: There seems nothing to be tried the way @Trini is trying.
Better was if Trini has told about his google search and the commentators would have directed/guided him well rather than telling solution. Trini are you there to listen me so that i could guide something

Comment: @SamiAkram: Yeah iam here iam listening and guide me :) thanks :)

Comment: Now Trini. @codef0rmer's code is also good, I have also posted mine. You can accept which seems feasible to you. However both are working, you can vote both if the work is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('table tr').click(function () {
    var BookId = $(this).children('td:eq(0)').html();
    var Title = $(this).children('td:eq(1)').html();
    var Author = $(this).children('td:eq(2)').html();

    $('div').html(
        'Book Id: ' + BookId + '<br />' +
        'Title: ' + Title + '<br />' + 
        'Author:' + Author + '<br />'
    );
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UPxB9/1/

Comment: @codeformer Great Work. Can you tell it in simple javascript. I suspect would not be much familiar to j-query

Comment: use div.innerHTML rather than appending. I think that's what Trini needs and I will see how it is done with j-query :)

Comment: @SamiAkram: The plain javascript code would be bit lengthy as we need to consider different browsers dependencies. Jquery solves that problem. So just download and include jquery.js from jquery.com in your page to make the above code work.

Comment: Now there remains only one reason of my answer to be accepted Hahaha. And that is if Trimi is there and he would be oldish like me :) Otherwise you have done it accurately

Answer (score 0):

Compare it with your Code its almost same just few changes mentioned

Only following function is added in your code and two lines more which are highlighted out of code

**Edit**
Add following function in your (already working) javascript tag on this page or in a js file which you are using in this page

```
function displayRowData(yourRow)
{
   var dv=document.getElementById('yourDivId');
   dv.innerHTML="<br>Name : "+ yourRow.children[0].innerHTML";
   dv.innerHTML += "<br>Place: "+yourRow.children[1].innerHTML";
   dv.innerHTML += "<br>Name : "+yourRow.children[2].innerHTML";
}

<form action="Options2" method="post">
 <table id="sorter" class="sortable" id="example" class="pretty">
 <tr>
<th>Book Id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Status</th>            
<th>Owner</th>
<th>Borrow Date</th>
<th>Return Date</th>
<th>Requested By</th>
<th>Actions</th>            
</tr>
<%
ArrayList  rs=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("news");
ListIterator itr=rs.listIterator();
int i=1;

while( itr.hasNext()){ 
%>
```

**Following Line is just modified it was already in your code**

```
<tr onclick='displayRowData(this)'> 

<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<% int Id = itr.nextIndex(); %>
<td><%=itr.next()%></td>    
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<% int Id2 = itr.nextIndex(); %>
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td> 
<td><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td><%=itr.next()%></td>
<% 
String Bname=rs.get(Id).toString();
System.out.println(Bname); 
String Stat=rs.get(Id2).toString();
System.out.println(Stat); 
if(!Stat.equals("Not Availible"))
{
%>
<td>
<input class="buttonir" type="Submit" name="X" value="<%=Bname %>"></td>
</tr>
<% 
}
}
%>
</table>
```

**Following line is added to your code**

```
<div id='yourDivId'></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry Previously i missed to add a div at the end. In which you can see your Results

Comment: Some mistakes in displayRowData function are removed. If want to know about innerHTML i can tell as well.

Comment: @codef0rmer sorry guys but both of the codes did not worked for me :( may be due to i use lot of external java script files in the same code to sort the table (dont know the exact reason) is there any other way arround?

Comment: If you are there surely a way is there. Only you can put full stop.

Comment: If your remaining program working fine for you. Do this
displayRowData(yourRow)
{
  alert(1);
  //leave remaining code as it is and tell me if you do not get alert.
}

Comment: Remember you don't need to change single line/word of my code. if your other code is working fine and paste <script> tag code also just above <form> tag

Comment: What html version are you using?

Comment: @Trini

Copy following code and paste as it is. all in HTML section on jsfiddle.net. Hopefully you will come to know your mistake

<script type="text/javascript">
    function hi(yourRow) {
        var dv = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
        dv.innerHTML = yourRow.children[0].innerHTML;
        dv.innerHTML += "<br>" + yourRow.children[1].innerHTML;
        dv.innerHTML += " " + yourRow.children[2].innerHTML;
    }
 </script>

<table border='2'>
<tr onClick='hi(this)'>
<td> hello </td> <td> hi </td><td> yes </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id='yourDivId'>
</div>

Comment: Html 4.01 (Sorry for the late response)

Comment: :) Thats ok. Follow Comment#5 (adding an alert(1)) and tell the update.

Comment: when i try it in jsfiddle.net everything works as expected may be that is because it is static data we use in jsfiddle. But when i copy the same code to my project nothing is working :(

Comment: Sorry for being busy elsewhere. The problem is just jsp. I have not been using it. Otherwise I could run it on my PC. Its quite tough to absorb that your code is fine but just with fully fair addition of few lines makes it not working. Do you know the way to add script tag in jsp becuse the way I have used is used in PHP I hoped it would be same but seems that this is actually the problem

Comment: It can be solved other way. Just be here do not go away. I will be here as well. Have you any javascript code already in this page?

Comment: @Trini are you there. Just make an alert('hello'); where ever you have javasript tag in this page. if you are able to do Then paste this function displyRowData right in that tag. It will work fine.

Comment: Its edited now. Read Previous comment also and Now follow the the text lines and use the code in answer as instructed. Hopefully now results would be better

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js"></script> that is the tag to add jquery to jsp and i will be here under your guidence :) thereis no other javascript written on this page except what you told me to write, i will try making alert and will revert you back with the results :)

Comment: As usual sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: The script you wrote is working as expected in IE but it is not working in both Chrome and Mozilla. All this time iam using Chrome. But by accident i checked with IE, For my surprise it is working with IE.